# Generate X.509 Self Signed Certificates for Production for WCF Webservice with OpenSSL

Tags: wcf, openssl, x509

how do I generate X.509 client and server self signed certificates for winserver 2003 production environment? I used makecert for test certs while following this article,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF?msg=4809268#xx4809268xx

I have OpenSSL for creating certs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [XCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) for doing this. It is built on top of OpenSSL and gives you GUI with templates like SSL client and SSL server cert.